# ngHide or ngShow based on number of children

Tags: angularjs

I know it is absolutely stupid thing to ask but I'm curious
is there a way do something like:

```
<div ng-show='this.children.length > 0'> // shown
   <div>

   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To add to @Josh David Miller answer, the following values are considered falsy in angular.

1)An Empty Array

2)An Empty String //Even a space is considered true

3)An Boolean with false

4)undefined

5)null

6) 0

So, David's answer can be written as,

```
<div ng-show="items.length">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

or even shorter,

```
<div ng-show="items">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this works i've tried it but how about when you apply a filter to items what then? I have this exact scenario but with a filter check my so question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459678/how-to-apply-the-ng-table-filter-selected-in-a-controller

Comment: This is no longer correct! AngularJS made a breaking change in version 1.3.0, they removed some falsey values, including the empty array `[]`. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29186652/1394336

Answer (score 34):

## AngularJS made a [breaking change in version 1.3.0](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/7960)!

Unfortunately, rajkamals answer is no longer correct.

From this version on, only these 6 values are considered falsy:

1. `false`
2. `null`
3. `undefined`
4. `NaN`
5. `0`
6. `""`

The values `'f'`, `'0'`, `'false'`, `'no'`, `'n'` and  `[]` (!) became truthy.

So using

```
<div ng-show="items">
    <!-- ... --->
</div>
```

can no longer be recommended if the div should only be visible if `items` contains at least 1 element, because even with `items = []` it will be displayed.

Instead, you could use

```
<div ng-show="items.length > 0">
    <!-- ... --->
</div>
```

Comment: It would be nice then to show how to do it right with the new breaking changes then..

Comment: @KornelitoBenito It should be `ng-show="items.length > 0"`, but given that I haven't worked with angular in quite some time, I'm hesitant to add this. Feel free to do so, if you've tested this!

Comment: Works as a charm!

Answer (score 17):

In AngularJS, we shouldn't think in terms of our view, but in terms of our model.

So you should ask yourself what generates the content inside your element. If it's dynamic, it comes from your model. So what model property could you access to give you the information you need?

Here's an ngRepeat example:

```html
<div ng-show="items.length > 0">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Seeing most of your questions, it seems like either you are not using Angular the "right" way or perhaps you are not able to ( because of project constraints perhaps! ).

Some general things for consideration.

1. If you are using $compile - it is a code smell. You wont need to use $compile in 95% of the cases. If you are using $compile, you are aware of it and you could not find any other way to do what you need to do. You are using it with great caution.
2. If you are "querying" the DOM to do anything - again its a possible smell. Again in 95% of the cases you wont need to do that. The right way here is to modify the model and let Angular handle the DOM.

These should be use the same way as you would ever use setTimeout 0 for example. Whenever you use it, it should feel like a hack.

If you are not in complete ( or atleast partial ) control of your HTML ( server is perhaps? ) it can get messy with Angular. Perhaps this is why you are attempting to do all these DOM manipulate-y stuff.

```
<div ng-show='this.children.length > 0'> // shown
   <div>

   </div>
</div>
```

This is one example where we are not sure who is in control. If you have access to the construct which is generating this html, you could also write it with ng-init!

```
<div ng-init="childElements = {{serverside variable}}" ng-show='childElements > 0'> // shown
   <div server-side-repeat>

   </div>
</div>
```

If you are forced to do these things in quite a lot of places, then perhaps Angular is not the right solution for you ?

Comment: I'm trying to marry asp.net unobtrusive validation and angular. So far unsuccesfully :(

Comment: I think asp.net and angular will work perfectly fine. It probably is the unobtrusive validation part that is causing you the grief. Cant you just do the client side validations with Angular?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS v1.3.3 => `ng-show="items"` didnt work for me as it evaluates object true,false,null,undefined. in case `items=[]`, ng-show still evaluated to true. Instead i had to use :

```
<div ng-show="items.length">
    <!-- ... --->
</div>
```

And worked!! Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

This also work perfectly....

```
<div ng-show="items.length">
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<!-- bind to your Dom element -->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Christopher pointed out, the accepted answer is no longer correct. Because an empty array still evaluates as truthy.

```
obj.children = []
<div ng-show='obj.children'> 
  As of Angular 1.3 this always shows if children exists as part of obj. 
</div>
```

### Current solution

In this case the array exists. But if you give angular the zero element of the array of the array to evaluate, and there is no such element, it will evaluate as false.

```
<div ng-show='obj.children[0]'> 
  This will not show because there is no element in the array at 0
</div>
```

You can also use this with [n] as any numbered element in the array to show only when the count is greater than n.
If you use obj.children[2], it will only show if you have 3 or more elements in the array.